# How to use Java Generics so that List<InterfaceImpl> can be returned for a method that has return type List<Interface>

Tags: java, generics, enums

I am trying to model a menuing system that can have menus which contain sub-menus. I wanted a generified `interface` for retrieving options from menus and from sub-menus via their parent menus and I am having trouble designing it while keeping it type-safe, flexible and free of compile-time 'incompatible types' errors. I tried to achieve my goal by using Java generics to specify a `Menu interface` for simple menus and a `ParentMenu interface` for parent menus which use generic type parameters for method parameters and return types.

I have a third `Enumerable interface` for representing the options available on a particular menu. The classes which `implement` the `Enumerable interface` are all `enum classes` that enumerate the options on a menu. A parent menu can hold numerous sub-menus, and I want a generified single method that allows a client of the parent menu class to get the options for any one of its sub-menus.

A parent menu concrete `class` has a method with a signature that specifies a return value of `List<Enumerable>`. I want to be able to return a `List<MenuOption>` where `MenuOption`  `implements` the `Enumerable interface`. However, I get an error which says that the `List<MenuOption>` I want to return is incompatible with a `List<Enumerable>`.

The basic `Menu interface`:

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

public interface Menu<T> {
    public List<T> getOptions();
}
```

The `ParentMenu interface`:

```
package example;

import java.util.List;

public interface ParentMenu<T,U> {
    public List<T> getSubMenuOptions(U subMenu);
}
```

The `Enumerable interface:

```
package example;

public interface Enumerable {
    public String getName();
}
```

Here is an implementation of the `Menu interface`:

```
package example;

import java.util.*;

public class SimpleMenu implements Menu<MenuOption> {

    private final Map<MenuOption, String> menuLinks;

    public SimpleMenu() {
        menuLinks = new HashMap<>();
        for(MenuOption option : MenuOption.values()) {
            //Totally arbitrary mapping to avoid adding extra classes and Selenium stuff that is not actually part of
            //the question I'm asking.
            menuLinks.put(option, option.getName());
        }
    }

    public final List<MenuOption> getOptions() {
        Set keys = menuLinks.keySet();
        List<MenuOption> options = new ArrayList<MenuOption>(keys);

        return options;
    }
}
```

Here is the `enum class` that enumerates the options on the `SimpleMenu`:

```
package example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum MenuOption implements Enumerable {

    OPTION_ONE("Option One"),
    OPTION_TWO("Option Two");

    private static final Map<String, MenuOption> lookup = new HashMap<>();

    private final String name;

    static {
        for (MenuOption option : MenuOption.values()) {
            lookup.put(option.toString(), option);
        }
    }

    private MenuOption(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public final static MenuOption getByName(final String name) {
        return lookup.get(name);
    }

    public final String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Here is an implementation of the `ParentMenu interface` which contains `SimpleMenu` as a sub-menu. The return statement below is where I am still getting an 'incompatible types' error because `List<Enumerable>` is not compatible with `List<MenuOption>`.

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public final class ConfigureMenu implements ParentMenu<Enumerable,ConfigureMenu.ConfigureSubMenu> {

    public static enum ConfigureSubMenu implements Enumerable {

        SIMPLE_MENU("An Option");

        private final String name;

        private static final Map<String, ConfigureSubMenu> lookup = new HashMap<>();

        static {
            for (ConfigureSubMenu subMenu : ConfigureSubMenu.values()) {
                lookup.put(subMenu.toString(), subMenu);
            }
        }

        private ConfigureSubMenu(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public final String getName() { return name; }

        public static ConfigureSubMenu getByName(String name) {
            return lookup.get(name);
        }
    }

    public final List<Enumerable> getSubMenuOptions(final ConfigureSubMenu subMenu) {
        switch(subMenu) {
            case SIMPLE_MENU:
                List<MenuOption> options = new SimpleMenu().getOptions();
                //This line causes the incompatible types error (List<Enumerable> is not compatible with List<MenuOption>)
                return options;
            default:
                return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I alter the signatures of my generic `interfaces` or the signatures of my concrete implementations so that I can get rid of this error and still have a flexible generic method that can return the options for any sub-menu contained by a parent menu?

NOTE: I have edited this question numerous times since it was asked and answered in order to improve the quality and to make it very clear what my problem and my desired objective were.

Comment: What line gives the compilation error and what does the compiler say *exactly*?

Comment: A `List<MenuOption>` is not usable as a `List<Enumerable>` because it doesn't provide `add(Enumerable)`, only `add(MenuOption)`.

Comment: In that `getSubMenuOptions` method, are you attempting to return more than one type of `MenuOption`?

Comment: Also, you have given a lot of unneeded code and it still does not compile (excluding the specific error you were asking about).

Comment: @user1803551 I cleaned up my question and removed anything that was not directly related to the error I was trying to correct. Does that make it clearer and more useful for anyone searching for a solution to the same problem?

Comment: I've again tried to edit my question so that it is more useful and clearer. I have two downvotes now and I don't know what else I can do to improve its quality. It would be helpful if you explained why you down-voted it and what I could do to make it better.

Comment: Imagine that you need to answer the question yourself. You say *"I have encountered a compile time error that doesn't make any sense to me"*, but you don't write what the error exactly is or on what line it is. Fine, we should be able to take your code, put it in our IDE and see for ourselves, but we can't since your code has more problems than you say (e.g. `ConfigureSubMenu` is undefined). Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): make it **minimal** (your problem can be shown in 5 lines now that I saw the correct answer) and also, it was answered a lot of times on the site.

Comment: @user1803551 I edited again to get to the MCVE you recommended. I realize that many have asked why `List<Interface>` isn't compatible with `List<InterfaceImpl>`, but my question was about how to design a generified way to handle that condition. I spent several hours searching Google and this site and reading generics tutorials trying to accomplish what I wanted. I had seen something like this before, so I knew it could be done. If this specific question was answered here before, I couldn't find it and I tried really hard. I am open to deleting and closing this one if it's a duplicate.

Comment: I don't see how this is an MCVE. When you copy-pasted your own code into your IDE before posting it, how many compiler errors did it show? My compiler gives 14 compilation errors.

Comment: Does the code have to compile? Or does it have to highlight the specific issue I'm trying to resolve? If you think it is necessary to have a compiling piece of code, then I will post the whole thing with lots of stuff that is not relevant to my question. My code, in its entirely, compiles now without errors. I was trying to post a minimal sample of it to keep my question short and to the point.

Comment: @user1803551 I have now added a complete, compiling example. The code compiles with a Java 1.8 compiler, except for the incompatible types error. Is this satisfactory?

Comment: Yes, much better. Although it is far from minimal (read again about MCVE) as I have stated before. Here is what your MCVE should look like: http://pastebin.com/0FTrcqgp. These ~10 lines of code are all you need to show everyone what the problem is and this is the type of code you should post. The solution for that code is the solution for yours. I am telling you this because had you done this yourself you would have reached the solution just by Googling about the "type mismatch" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java generics can be a little tricky.  Your method returns `List<Enumerable>` which means "a List which holds *exactly the type Enumerable*".  You are returning a `List<MenuOption>`, which is *not* the same type.  instead, you should define `getSubMenuOptions` in ParentMenu as `public List<? extends T> getSubMenuOptions(U subMenu);`, where `List<? extends T>` means "a List which holds some type which implements T (in this case Enumerable)".  In `ConfigureMenu`, the method implementation should be defined as `public final List<? extends Enumerable> getSubMenuOptions`.

Many more helpful details around working with generics are [available here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html).

Comment: So I made the change you suggested: public List<? extends T> getSubMenuOptions(U subMenu); in the ParentMenu interface, but I am still getting the same incompatible types error.

Comment: @Selena in ConfigureMenu, you are defining the method as `public final List<? extends Enumerable> getSubMenuOptions(`, right?

Comment: Yes. `ConfigureMenu` implements the `ParentMenu interface` and for the type parameter `T` from `ParentMenu`, it expects an `Enumerable`. I have updated my question to reflect the use of a wildcard extending `T` in `ParentMenu`.

Comment: @Selena - see my previous comment about ConfigureMenu.

Comment: Okay that works. I am accepting your answer. Thank you so much! This really expanded my understanding of generics.

Comment: Can you edit your answer and put in the detail that `ConfigureMenu`'s `getSubMenuOptions(final ConfigureSubMenu subMenu)` method needs to have a return type of `List<? extends Enumerable>`? I don't want anyone to have to read these comments to find that detail.

Answer (score 0):

`List<MenuOption>` is not a type of `List<Enumerable>`, since you can't add any any `Enumerable` to it. You could instead return a `List<? extends Enumerable>`:

```
public final List<? extends Enumerable> getSubMenuOptions
   (final ConfigureSubMenu subMenu) {

    switch(subMenu) {

        case SIMPLE_SUB_MENU:
            List<MenuOption> options = new SimpleSubMenu().getOptions();
            return options;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's more of a ripple effect; you'd have to change the `ParentMenu` interface for this to fully work.